# What is the type hint for built-in types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm writing a function that receives a `type` as a parameter (similar to `isinstance`).
What should be the type-hint so that users have a clear idea of what the parameter is?

For example, what would be the type of `classinfo` below if `isinstance` had type hints?

```py
def isinstance(object: Any, classinfo: _____):
    pass
```

---

EDIT: pending a long discussion, adding the code to the actual function:

I'm traversing a JSON object and executing a `Callable` on a specific type. I want the users of this function to have an easy time understanding what the `execute_on_type` parameter is.

```py
def traverse_json_obj(jobj: list or dict, callable: Callable, execute_on_type: __??__):
    if isinstance(jobj, execute_on_type):
        yield callable(jobj)
    if isinstance(jobj, dict):
        for _, v in jobj.items():
            if isinstance(v, execute_on_type):
                yield callable(v)
            else:
                for child_res in traverse_json_obj(v, callable, execute_on_type):
                    yield child_res
    elif isinstance(jobj, list):
        for item in jobj:
            for item_val in traverse_json_obj(item, callable, execute_on_type):
                yield item_val
```

Then the following:

```py
jobj = {'id': {'num': 1, 'str': 'two'}, 'list': [{'num': 3, 'str': 'four', 'list': [5, 6]}]}
list(traverse_json_obj(jobj, print, int))
```

should yield

```
1
3
5
6
```

Comment: built-in is not a type.

Comment: The type you want is simply `type`.

Comment: There is no type "built in". The type for a `tuple` would be `tuple[int, str, float]` or whatever.

Comment: so, what is the generalization of `str`, `int`, `dict` etc?

Comment: @JoeyBaruch `object`... but that applies to *anything* and is almost certainly not what you want. Again, there is no base type for "all built-in types" other than the base type for *every* type, i.e. `object`. Your use-case is not exactly clear, could you elaborate?

Comment: Wait, this is confusing. What, exactly, are you trying to annotate? Can you just give a concrete example? `isinstance` accepts either a type or a tuple of types as its second argument, but this has no restriction that it should be a built-in type, so this is not making much sense

Comment: Are you looking for something like `type | tuple[type, ...]`?

Comment: @wjandrea maybe `type | tuple[type, ...]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not familiar with the `...`

Comment: @juanpa Right, fixed! I forgot tuples have different semantics than lists.

Comment: @JoeyBaruch do you *actually* need to type-hint `isinstance`? Because the second argument actually takes on a variety of complicated forms. Again, can you please elaborate on what you are actually trying to accomplish directly? The type-hint for any type (i.e. a class object) is simply `type` which is itself a class, a class that creates classes (i.e. a metaclass...) but again, it is entirely unclear if this is what you mean

Comment: @Joey The ellipsis is to indicate a variable-length tuple. Tuples are usually heterogenous and fixed length, which means each index would be hinted separately, but in this case, it's homogenous and variable-length.

Comment: `def check_instance(x: Any, check_type: type): return isinstance(x, check_type)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Added an edit for you. I was thinking I could just do `str or int` but that would refer to **instances** of `int` or `str` which would be confusing

Comment: @JoeyBaruch no, that wouldn't be a valid type annotation at all! You can't use `or` in a type annotation, you mean either `typing.Union` or since 3.9, you can use `|`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought that edit was faithful to the intent of the OP. What was your reasoning for rolling it back?

Comment: @Brian you obliterated all the extra, extremely relevant stuff the OP added right as you were editing.

Comment: OK,so you just want to use `typing.Type` or since 3.9 just `type`. But it is generic. So, suppose you wanted to accept the class `Foo` or any derived class, e.g. `FooChild`, then you could do `Type[Foo]`, or for unrelated types, `Type[int, str, complex]` for example. You can also use a bound type variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I would consider the demo of their `traverse_json_obj` function irrelevant noise for most readers of this question. The only relevant bit is that they want the type hint to be compatible with what `isinstance` takes, no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I'd actually love to know your take on @Brian's point re the `traverse_json_obj` function, as I too excluded it originally from the question feeling it was noisy, then added it because you asked what I'm actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `isinstance` is one of three things:

1. A type
2. A tuple
3. (In Python 3.10 or later) a `typing.Union`.

The problem is that not just *any* tuple is allowed: each element of the tuple must be one of the three things listed above, leading to a recursively defined type. Essentially, it's a "tree" of types built with tuples (and `Union`s). I'm not sure how, or even if, you can represent such a type using the `typing` module. Prior to Python 3.10, you could write

```
TypeTuple = typing.Union[type, typing.Tuple['TypeTuple',...]]
```

though `mypy`'s ability to use such a hint is (or was) limited.